# Jackson JSON case insensitive deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have json

```
{
"containers": {
    "USER": {
        "wifPk": "L2x26xxMmKshontu.....qEMh5TCWyf"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to read container property `USER` value as case-insensitive. Because it can be `user` or `USER`.
Starting Jackson 2.5.0 I know it's possible to deserialize json to class using:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);  
CarInfo info = objectMapper.readValue(data, CarInfo.class);
```

But I can't use class. My code doesn't work:

```
privateKey = data.getJson().path("containers").path("user").path("wifPk").asText();
```

Is there working solution?